# Data Visualisation in R , Sorting the geom_raster()

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-raster

I have the below data visualisation for life expectancy of Asia using gapminder data-set, How can I change the plot to order it based on countries with higher life expectancy downwards?

Here is my code :

```
install.packages("gapminder")
library(gapminder)
 Asia_sample2 <- gapminder %>% filter (gapminder$continent =="Asia")
    p1 <- ggplot(data = Asia_sample2, aes(x = year , y = country , fill = lifeExp  ))
    p1 + geom_raster() +scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="red") + 
      theme_bw() +
       labs(title = "Estimated Life Expectancy in Asia , Years(1952-2007)")
```

Comment: I am using R you just need to do below and you have access to gapminder install.packages("gapminder")
library(gapminder)

Answer (score 3):

You could create a column with the age mean by country and then sort the levels of the factor `country` based on the age mean values e.g.:

```
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Asia_sample2 <- gapminder %>% group_by(country) %>% 
mutate(lifeExp_mean = mean(lifeExp)) %>% filter (continent =="Asia") %>% 
  arrange(lifeExp_mean) %>% ungroup() 

Asia_sample2$country <- factor(Asia_sample2$country, levels=unique(Asia_sample2$country))

p1 <- ggplot(data = Asia_sample2, aes(x = year , y = country , fill = lifeExp  ))
p1 + geom_raster() + scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="red") + 
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "Estimated Life Expectency in Asia , Years(1952-2007)")
ggsave("plot.png", width = 10, height = 5)
```

[image]